# let docker access consul in docker compose

Tags: docker, consul, go-micro

The docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  rs:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
  consul:
    image: "consul"
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
    hostname: "abc"
```

`rs` is a go micro server app which will access consul and the consul address configured in a file like:

```
"microservice": {
        "serviceName": "hello",
        "registry": "consul=abc:8500",
```

However this don't work, the `rs` report error log:

```
register error: Put http://abc:8500/v1/agent/service/register: dial tcp: lookup abc on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

I can access consul ui in host machine by http://127.0.0.1:8500, it works properly.

How to configure the network let rs can access consul?

Comment: `consul` should work as a host name communicating between containers within the same `docker-compose.yml` file.  You don't need to set `hostname:`.  (It has the same effect as running _e.g._ `sudo hostname stackoverflow.com` on your local Linux system.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed hostname of the consul container, however `rs` service is not aware of this, and it attempts to resolve `abc` by querying default DNS server which is `127.0.0.11` port `53`. You can see this in error message, since this DNS server is unable to resolve `abc` as it has no information about it.

The easiest way to solve this, and have it working in docker-compose, on the network created between the services in docker-compose is following:

```
version: '3'

services:
  rs:
    build: .
    # image: aline:3.7
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    # command: sleep 600
    networks:
      rs-consul:
  consul:
    image: "consul"
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
    hostname: "abc"
    networks:
      rs-consul:
        aliases:
          - abc

networks:
  rs-consul:
```

This will create new network `rs-consul` (check with `docker network ls`, it will have some prefix, mine had `working_directory_name_` as prefix). And on this network the Consul machine has [alias](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) `abc`. Now your `rs` service should be able to reach Consul service via `http://abc:8500/`

I have used commented lines (`image:alpine:3.7` and `command: sleep 600`) instead of `build: .`, to test the connection, since I don't have your `rs` service code to use in `build:`. Once containers are started, I used `docker exec -it <conatiner-id> sh` to start shell on `rs` container, then installed `curl` and was able to retrieve Consul UI page via following command:

```
curl http://abc:8500/ui/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works, thx. As docker doc says: "By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name." Why this won't work in this example? If access url "consul:8500", the error log will be "no such host"

Comment: Default container name is same as container ID and is changed on every rebuild. This is not same as service tag in YAML file. E.g. when I ran the docker-compose on my machine  I had: `05b35aa56c19        consul` in the output of `docker ps`. To access this consul from the other container I had to do `curl http://05b35aa56c19:8500`. For name to be set you need to use either `hostname: consul` as in the example above or `conainer_name: consul` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name). In either case, this name will be available only on that particular docker network

Comment: But in docker doc about pgsql example in https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/, the db connection string is "postgres://db:5432". The "db" is a service name. This is confusing, why this can work?

Comment: You are right, service name from docker-compose YAML is discoverable by other containers on the same network. I was able to use `dig` to resolve IP address of `consul` service, even without setting `container_name` or `hostname`, being set. Can you provide minimum configuration for the `rs` service to reproduce this issue? Because it might be issue with that container configuration, as plain alpine image is able to resolve `consul`. Try using `docker exec -it <container-id> sh` to test if you able to resolve `consul` manually using `nslookup consul` or `dig consul`.

Comment: I can not reproduce this after I run docker-compose down. I am new to docker, so ahead of that, I did rm -f image before docker-compose up. The doc says docker-compose down will remove the network also, maybe that's the reason I am keeping failure on that

Comment: Container must be running when you execute `docker exec -it <container-id> sh`. First bring up your docker-compose setup with `docker-compose up`, then find the container ID with `docker ps` and use it in the `exec` command. However, it's possible that `rs` container shuts down if it's not able to start successfully, in that case you will not be able to `exec` into it. What repo are you using to `build: .` the `rs` service? Is it available on github or some other public git service?